# Images are corrupt on downloading the PDF file

Tags: graphics, viewers, overleaf

I'm having a problem with images, I'm using overleaf to typeout my report but facing problem with images. I'm using overleaf to do so.
Here's the screenshot.

[image]

[image]

The image looks fine in the viewer but when I'm downloading the PDF file, its not. PLease help !

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What is the file format of your image (`.png`, `.jpg`, `.eps`, `.pdf`, something else)? Which viewer do you use after you download the document (Adobe Reader, SumatraPDF, web browser viewer, something else)?

Comment: Could you prepare a *minimal* example document on Overleaf that makes use of the image file in question and then make it public?  Read-only access is sufficient.